# Cycles Material + WeightPaint + Drawing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, weight-painting

Is it possible to assign a shader or texture to certain parts on the mesh where the weightpaint was drawn? just like we would use it with particles + weight paint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! 
This is typical, search for an answer, found nothing.
Post in stackexchange, found the answer immediately..

[Here](https://blenderartists.org/t/mixing-two-materials-using-vertex-weight-texture-paint-cycles/679843/2) is it described what i was looking for!